# Secure flow from Client to OAuth2 to Server to Client again

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0

I'm not sure if this is specific to the discord OAuth2 flow but I'll mention that I'm currently trying to get a user's discord id for use later.

My current flow is as follows:

- User clicks on button on client which redirects to discord auth link
- Discord sends code callback to firebase function
- Firebase sends for Token+Refresh from auth server
- Firebase stores user id and such(iffy here)
- Firebase sends confirmation back to the Client

I need the UID of the person calling this function in order to store the data into the correct document on firestore. I was originally going to consider going with:

- User clicks on button on client which redirects to discord auth link
- Discord sends code callback to client
- Client sends code to Firestore Function
- Firebase sends for Token+Refresh from auth server
- Firebase stores user id
- Firebase sends confirmation back to the Client

but I'm worried about the insecurity mentioned here: https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#oauth2-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided that it doesn't matter if the client (or anyone for that matter) has access to the code callback since I'm using it to fetch for the actual token+refresh anyways. The code is useless without the app_id and app_secret anyways.